# Algorithm about ETA (Estimated time of arrival)

Tags: gps

The question is simple and direct.Please help.

I am working on bus ETA projects where all the datum i get are:

1.Real time GPS locations from bus

2.Distance between each stop

Do we need more data than these?

My Big question is:
How to make use of these data to calculate the ETA for customer?

My thoughts:
ETA is all about distance/speed,
so at first: I tried to simply get distance from 2 GPS coordinates to calculate
speed and use stop's distance to calculate ETA.

i.e.

```
  while(true){

    ETA = stopDis/2ptSpeed;

    stopDis = stopDis - 2ptDis;
    }
```

and upDATE next stop when `stopDis<0`
However, the problem is that the GPS datum will jump quite wildly and hence the
speed calculated is really messy.

Broken downed Question: How to smooth the GPS datum? Kalman Filter? Averaging?
Have heard of those but does not really know what to do ESPECIALLY Kalman filter!

Comment: If i would like to implement a relatively precise ETA that react to real life such as traffic jams/accidents > increase ETA, what are the minimum data that needed to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of traffic and not-straight lines, distances and speed alone are not reliable indicators.

I think that your best bet is to use the history of the line to compare the current distance with the average distance at that time in the line, and to deduce a deviation from the average ETA.

Comment: use the gps data to calculate the distance travelled, and hence using the remaining distance between stops to times the portion of time needed? i don't know if that would be the case as what if there is an accident happened? Real time calculation is really important as all i want is a relatively precise ETA that changed in real time.

Comment: You can't predict future accidents, but if an accident happens in front of the bus, the ETA will start to slip as soon as the bus slows. I don't think that you can do better with a single GPS, without using global trafic data.

Comment: The problem is,how to implement and what is the algorithm in ETA implementation. What are the equations and formula needed in predicting the ETA in the end. simply comparing the bus schedule won't give me actual ETA if something happens during the journey.

Comment: The algorithm is simply to use a rule of three to project the ETA by comparing the average distance in the history at the current time with the real-time distance. remaining time = (avg time)*(curr. dist)/(avg dist)

Comment: What is the average time/average distance you mentioned.
If remaining time = (total time)*(total dist-current dist)/(total dist) then i understand very clearly.
but your equation seems to have 2 unknowns in 1 equations?
Sorry for being dumb, i really want to get things clearly

Comment: do you mean,for example, the bus travelled 2 mins, compare the current dis to the previous distance that the bus travelled 2 mins. Then use the (previous whole journery time - 2mins) * (avg dis)/(current dis)

Comment: Something like that yes. It's just to give an idea, not a production-ready algorithm. You have to adjust to real data, for instance if the lines are very twisty you might have to add waypoints (like additionnal stops) along the way and use distances to these waypoints for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that simple. What if there are lots of traffic lights between 2 stops or different speed limits.

And you have the gps coordinates so you can calculate distance, but that isn't the distance over the road. So you need to have someway to get the real distance the bus needs to travel (Perhaps the google maps api can help).

So to answer the  "Do we need more data than these?" question: yes, i think you do.

Comment: just simply ignore the traffic light i guess, i also have the data of the bus stop's coordinates, does that help?

Comment: You still have to calculate the distance the bus really needs to travel not the direct distance between 2 coordinates. But if you want to ignore all that it's just like you said.  ETA = distance / speed.

Comment: i already have the distance data between stops, the distance between 2 coordinates are the bus movements which i used to calculate the remaining distance. and hence reduce the actual ETA as time passed by

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: The bus schedule already contains info about how much time is needed between stops on average. If you can just read from the GPS position if the bus is on a stop or between two stops you should be able to make a fairly accurate prediction.

I'm guessing you are talking about busses in a city, where GPS signals are weak and bus stops are not far apart.

Edit: This could be further improved with data about current traffic.

Comment: The historical data could help in estimating the ETA, but in real life traffic conditions varies, the best way is to implement the historical data such as bus schedule and real time calculation. But that makes things more complicated. And the most important question is: how?

Comment: Well, how good is "good enough"? What could be a simple solution? When would that solution fail? How could you improve it?

Comment: maybe adding weighted between real time calculations and bus schedule helps? or comparing the calculation and schedule to choose between one of those? it is really messy when dealing with the logic behind

Comment: Try to start simple. Calculate how much time the bus needs to reach the next stop, then add time to reach destination according to schedule. If you have traffic data, add time to segments where traffic is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Collect travel time data from stop to stop on a continuous basis. Derive an expected travel time between stops from this historical data to use as a baseline. this can be continuously updated. Initial ETA at a stop is time of last stop plus most recent travel time average. If you have continuous GPS data, you can adjust in real time from that.